# Adding javascript to a XML file transformed with XSLT using a Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, greasemonkey

As follow up to my question here - [How to transform an XML file with XSLT, using a Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998446/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-with-xslt-using-a-greasemonkey-script) - I'm facing another problem:

I want to use some basic javascript functions in my XSL template in order to control the display of some divs. However, no matter how I include these javascript functions, they don't seem to be recognized. I already investigated a lot but I can't seem to get around it.

I tried 2 things:

- Adding the javascript in the XSL template in a `<script>` tag
- Appending a new `<script>` tag in the Greasemonkey script itself

I would prefer not to use jQuery or an external JS file (which I also tried) to keep it as simple as possible, but if that would solve the problem I'm open to change the whole thing!

In either case when I call the function I get a `ReferenceError: x is not defined`. I do see that the javascript code sits nicely in the final HTML result though. When I use Firebug to append a new `<script>` tag with a simple function that alerts "hello" to a plain html page then it works perfectly. It's only when this is done on top of a XSLT transformation things go wrong (for the sake of simplicity I'm just using a simple function to show an alert box).

Here's my sample data:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Results>
      <Result>
          <Listings total="2">
              <Res>
                  <Result index="0">
                      <id>123456</id>
                      <name>My Business</name>
                      <category>Restaurants</category>
                      <phone>9872365</phone>
                  </Result>
              </Res>
              <Res>
                  <Result index="1">
                      <id>876553</id>
                      <name>Some Other Business</name>
                      <category>Restaurants</category>
                      <phone>9834756</phone>
                  </Result>
              </Res>
          </Listings>
      </Result>
  </Results>
```

---

Here's the first attempt where I just added a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` tag:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Test XML Renderer
// @description stylesheet for xml results
// @include     *
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var xsl_str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n\
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">\n\
    <xsl:output method="html"/>\n\
    <xsl:template match="/">\n\
        <html>\n\
            <head><script type="text/javascript">function hello() {alert("hello")};</script></head>\n\
            <body>\n\
                <table id="results" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n\
                    <thead>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                            <th class="name">id</th>\n\
                            <th class="name">category ID</th>\n\
                            <th class="name">name</th>\n\
                            <th class="name">phone</th>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                    </thead>\n\
                    <tbody>\n\
                        <xsl:for-each select="Results/Result/Listings/Res">\n\
                            <tr>\n\
                                <td class="small" width="120">\n\
                                    <a href="#" onclick="hello()"><xsl:value-of select="Result/id"/></a>\n\
                                </td>\n\
                                <td class="small" width="120">\n\
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/category"/>\n\
                                </td>\n\
                                <td class="small" width="120">\n\
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/name"/>\n\
                                </td>\n\
                                <td class="small" width="120">\n\
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/phone"/>\n\
                                </td>\n\
                            </tr>\n\
                        </xsl:for-each>\n\
                    </tbody>\n\
                </table>\n\
            </body>\n\
        </html>\n\
    </xsl:template>\n\
</xsl:stylesheet>\n\
';

var processor   = new XSLTProcessor ();
var dataXSL     = new DOMParser ().parseFromString (xsl_str, "text/xml");

processor.importStylesheet (dataXSL);

var newDoc      = processor.transformToDocument (document);

//-- These next lines swap the new, processed doc in for the old one...
window.content  = newDoc;

document.replaceChild (
    document.importNode (newDoc.documentElement, true),
    document.documentElement
);
```

---

Here's my other attempt where I add the "hello" function outside the XSL template:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Test XML Renderer
// @description stylesheet for xml results
// @include     *
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var xsl_str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n\
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">\n\
    <xsl:output method="html"/>\n\
    <xsl:template match="/">\n\
        <html>\n\
            <head></head>\n\
            <body>\n\
                <table id="results" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n\
                    <thead>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                            <th class="name">id</th>\n\
                            <th class="name">category ID</th>\n\
                            <th class="name">name</th>\n\
                            <th class="name">phone</th>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                    </thead>\n\
                    <tbody>\n\
                        <xsl:for-each select="Results/Result/Listings/Res">\n\
                            <tr>\n\
                                <td class="small" width="120">\n\
                                    <a href="#" onclick="hello()"><xsl:value-of select="Result/id"/></a>\n\
                                </td>\n\
                                <td class="small" width="120">\n\
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/category"/>\n\
                                </td>\n\
                                <td class="small" width="120">\n\
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/name"/>\n\
                                </td>\n\
                                <td class="small" width="120">\n\
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/phone"/>\n\
                                </td>\n\
                            </tr>\n\
                        </xsl:for-each>\n\
                    </tbody>\n\
                </table>\n\
            </body>\n\
        </html>\n\
    </xsl:template>\n\
</xsl:stylesheet>\n\
';

var processor   = new XSLTProcessor ();
var dataXSL     = new DOMParser ().parseFromString (xsl_str, "text/xml");

processor.importStylesheet (dataXSL);

var newDoc      = processor.transformToDocument (document);

var script = "function hello() {alert('hello')};";
var newElem = newDoc.createElement('script');
newElem.type = 'text/javascript';
newElem.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(script));
newDoc.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(newElem);

//-- These next lines swap the new, processed doc in for the old one...
window.content  = newDoc;

document.replaceChild (
    document.importNode (newDoc.documentElement, true),
    document.documentElement
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't use `onclick`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627478/331508).  This goes triple for userscripts, as there are additional scope and/or sandbox conflicts.

Also, it's a poor idea to try and add JS into the XSLT file/text, and there is no need for script injection in this case either.

Use the script to do whatever JS manipulation you have in mind.  For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _XML Renderer with javascript functionality
// @description Stylesheet and javascript for xml results
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*.xml
// @resource    xslFile  Q_17998446_transform.xsl
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==

var xsl_str     = GM_getResourceText ("xslFile");
var processor   = new XSLTProcessor ();
var dataXSL     = new DOMParser ().parseFromString (xsl_str, "text/xml");

processor.importStylesheet (dataXSL);

var newDoc      = processor.transformToDocument (document);

//-- These next lines swap the new, processed doc in for the old one...
window.content  = newDoc;

document.replaceChild (
    document.importNode (newDoc.documentElement, true),
    document.documentElement
);

//-- Use JS to smarten-up the new document.
var firstCols   = document.querySelectorAll ("#results td:first-child");

for (var J = firstCols.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var tdNode = firstCols[J];
    tdNode.style.cursor = "pointer";
    tdNode.addEventListener ("click", clickCellHandler, false);
}

function clickCellHandler (zEvent) {
    var cellContents = zEvent.target.textContent.trim ();

    alert ('The clicked cell contains "' + cellContents + '".');
}
```

where `Q_17998446_transform.xsl` is a file saved in the same folder from where you install your script (you may need to uninstall, and reinstall, the script).

`Q_17998446_transform.xsl` contains this, exactly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <table id="results" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="name">id</th>
                            <th class="name">category ID</th>
                            <th class="name">name</th>
                            <th class="name">phone</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Results/Result/Listings/Res">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="small" width="120">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/id"/>
                                </td>
                                <td class="small" width="120">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/category"/>
                                </td>
                                <td class="small" width="120">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/name"/>
                                </td>
                                <td class="small" width="120">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Result/phone"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

---

When you run that script on the appropriate XML file, it adds a click-handler to the first table column (sans header) -- the "Web 2.0" way.

When one of the first-column cells is clicked, it alerts, for example:

> The clicked cell contains "876553".

Comment: Great, thanks again for your help! And thanks for introducing me to the world of event handlers, they work perfectly.