# How to edit Image URL from RSS feed using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, rss

I want to change the URL of image attribute. Below is my RSS feed doc.I just want to replace the path of image URL attribute with other.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<channel>
    <title> Debug</title>
    <link>https://images/image</link>
    <description>This forum is focused on the  Test service. You can post questions, answers, bugs or ideas for improvement.</description>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <generator>ActiveForums  5.0</generator>
    <copyright>Copyright [year] by GLOBO Plc.</copyright>
    <lastBuildDate>Fri, 24 Oct 2014 03:44:18 GMT</lastBuildDate>

    <image><url>http://images/image1</url>
    <title>GO!AppZone GO!AppZone Debug</title>      <link>https://Community/Developer-Forum/aff/5/afv/topicsview</link></image>
    <item>
        <title>lalalala</title>
        <description>oioioioiooi &lt;img src=&#39;https://DesktopModules/ActiveForums/themes/_default/emoticons/tongue.gif&#39; align=&quot;absmiddle&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; class=&quot;afEmoticon&quot; /&gt;</description>
        <link>https://Community/Developer-Forum/aff/5/aft/12/afv/topic</link>
        <dc:creator>ant lia</dc:creator>
        <pubDate>Fri, 24 Oct 2014 03:44:18 GMT</pubDate>
        <guid>https://Community/Developer-Forum/aff/5/aft/12/afv/topic</guid>
        <slash:comments>1</slash:comments>
    </item>
</channel></rss>
```

Is there any why to replace URL path using javascript or jQuery.

Please help to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: change it for who, and why? if you need everyone to see the change, you need to change the software that builds the feed.

Comment: I want to edit the specified URL path with other path. Like my url contains a path of LOGO image. But I want to change that logo.

Comment: yes, but why do you want to change it? do you just want to show to changed feed to a single user, do you want to feed the updated feed to another service, do you want to just download the new feed, etc? whether this is possible depends on what you're trying to do. there's no point in changing it just to change it, so  then the question becomes "what are you changing it for", and is it a use that's practical for js to accomplish? without details, can't say. if i had to guess, i would lean towards "no", but i need details to make the call; some client-side feed readers would like it, others no

Comment: I want to show this to everyone. Actually I am using third party CMS and they have provided only dll file. So I don't have code behind file for that. So I want some script which I can use in .ascx file to change my LOGO.

Comment: ok, now i understand. since the ascx is a server-side thing, you can't use client-side javascript to change it. sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform an XML file with XSLT, using a Greasemonkey script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998446/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-with-xslt-using-a-greasemonkey-script)